# "Where you'd like to work" on Job Preferences page is very restrictive

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

"Where you'd like to work" on the Job Preferences page is very restrictive; I can only fill in specific cities, but not countries or "anywhere".

I think many people willing to relocate aren't thinking of a specific city, so while "anywhere" is perhaps a bit much, a specific country or "anywhere in EU" probably isn't that uncommon.

I managed to fill in what I wanted by removing the `disabled` attribute in the web inspector by the way :-) Although I'm not sure if that actually affects searches and the like.

---

[image]

Comment: `I think many people willing to relocate aren't thinking of a specific city` and how do you know this? But I agree regarding the "Anywhere in EU"

Comment: @kemicofa I think the biggest issue is just that Martin can't select his entire country (New Zealand), never mind sub regions of it, as an option.

Comment: It's actually a bit more complex than that @DanNeely, I moved to NZ for the fun of it as my previous position was remote; it was always meant to be a temporary thing as my visa isn't permanent (I don't have a NZ work visa). Now that I resigned, I'm open to relocating pretty much ... anywhere (or open to staying in NZ for that matter, if someone will sponsor my visa).

Comment: This screenshot reminds me that the "willing to work remotely" option isn't great, either. Personally, I'd check a box labelled "*only* willing to work remotely."